# How to get FontType of a font in .NET 5?

Tags: c#, .net-5

With the Win32 API function [`EnumFontFamiliesExA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-enumfontfamiliesexa) or [`EnumFontFamiliesExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-enumfontfamiliesexw), we can get FontType from the lpProc callback:

```
int CALLBACK EnumFontFamExProc(
   const LOGFONT    *lpelfe,
   const TEXTMETRIC *lpntme,
         DWORD      FontType,
         LPARAM     lParam
);
```

In .NET 5, we can get all installed fonts with the [`InstalledFontCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.text.installedfontcollection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#definition) class.

However, I can't find any property indicating whether a FontFamily object is a vector or a raster font.

Is it possible to get font type without calling Win32 API in .NET 5?

Comment: [TextMetrics.PitchAndFamily](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.textmetrics.pitchandfamily) Property. => [GetOutlineTextMetrics()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getoutlinetextmetricsw) -> [OUTLINETEXTMETRIC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-outlinetextmetricw) -> [TEXTMETRIC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-textmetricw) -> `tmPitchAndFamily` member.

Comment: Font metrics assume a device context, where the Font is selected. The TextMetrics instead specify the physical Font metrics of the selected Font. See: [VisualStyleRenderer.GetTextMetrics()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstylerenderer.gettextmetrics) and [Glyphs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.glyphs), [GlyphRun](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.glyphrun) -> [GlyphTypeface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.glyphtypeface) ...

Comment: ...related to [GetGlyphOutline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getglyphoutlinew)